# Make Google Assistant asking a text input, and send to a Webhook

Tags: google-home, google-assistant

I have a local server, asking to ChatGPT a color combination to create an ambient according to the input provided using my Philips Hue lights.
Example: "ambient sunset at Maldive", ChatGPT create the combination and my server sends command to lights. Everything works fine, I also easily create a custom command on Siri to make it, but I can't do in Google Assistant (builtin in the TV).
So I want that, once my custom scene "Ambient Light" starts, Assistant should:

- ask me to describe the ambient I want
- send the text to my server (POST REST API)

I found in Google Home an automation script editor, but I can just send commands to devices. I can't find a custom webhook. I also see that Actions App is no more available.

What's the right way to make it? There is a command builder as in Siri?
Even using IFTTT, it's missing the Input part. Anyway, I'd like avoid IFTTT since I can have just 1 applet for free.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Google Assistant doesn't offer a direct way to request custom commands like Siri's command builder. Additionally, with the discontinuation of the Actions SDK(Dialogflow), the landscape has changed.

One alternative you might explore is the Google Assistant SDK. This SDK allows you to embed the Google Assistant into your own devices or applications. However, it's important to note that this might be more suitable for a product or application where the integration of Google Assistant makes sense.

Regarding your specific use case of asking for ambient descriptions and sending them to your server, you might need to consider workarounds. IFTTT is one option, but as you mentioned, it has limitations on the number of free applets.

Another approach could be looking into Google Assistant Routines. While Routines are typically predefined commands, you might be able to leverage certain phrases to trigger your desired effect. However, this wouldn't provide the dynamic and personalized input you're seeking.